# Produce a boxplot for multiple ACFs

Tags: r, plot, time-series, boxplot

I used the following to run `forecast::Acf` over about 200 columns. Now I would like to generate a boxplot showing the distribution of correlation values at lag 1:36.

```
## a simple example
d <- data.frame(ts1 = rnorm(100), ts2 = rnorm(100))
acorr <- apply(d, 2, Acf)
```

What I now want is a boxplot where x-values are 1,2 and the y-values are ACF for `ts1` and `ts2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have multiple time series stored in a data frame `d` (each column is one series), we can use the following to obtain ACF up to lag 36 (`nrow(d) >> 36` to make sense!):

```
## for data frame `d`
acfs <- sapply(d, function (u) c(acf(u, lag.max = 36, plot = FALSE)$acf)[-1])
```

- R base function `acf` is sufficient for the job; set `lag.max = 36` and `plot = FALSE`;
- `acf` returns a list, and we want `$acf` field. Note, this is a 3D arrary, so we want to flatten it into a vector using `c()`;
- ACF at lag 0 is 1 and is not of interest, so we drop it by `[-1]`;
- `sapply` would return a matrix, each column giving ACF for each series.

In case you have time series stored in a matrix (either an ordinary matrix or one with "mts" class), we use `apply` rather than `sapply`:

```
## for matrix `d`
acfs <- apply(d, 2L, function (u) c(acf(u, lag.max = 36, plot = FALSE)$acf)[-1])
```

To produce a boxplot, simply use:

```
boxplot(acfs)
```

[image: boxplot]

---

Why is `$acf` a 3D array. Because `acf` function can handle multiple time series directly. Try:

```
## whether `d` is data frame or matrix, it is converted to "mts" inside `acf`
oo <- acf(d, lag.max = 36, plot = FALSE)$acf
```

The problem is, in this case, cross-correlation (CCF) is also computed.

---

> On the x-axis I want 1-36, not `ts1` and `ts2`. I need the distribution of at each lag over time series. If you can fix that your answer is very good.

Ei? Did I misread your question. Well, in that case, you just `boxplot` the transpose of `acfs`:

```
boxplot(t(acfs))
```

[image: trans]

Comment: On the x axis i want 1-36, not ts1 and ts2. The distribution of at each lag over all columns. If you can fix that your answere is very good.