# Apply autocorrelation function acf() to elements of set of vectors by group in a data frame

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame `DF` which looks like this:

```
 ID      Area time
1  1 182.685    1
2  2 182.714    1
3  3 182.275    1
4  4 211.928    1
5  5 218.804    1
6  6 183.445    1
...
1  1 184.334    2
2  2 196.765    2
3  3 186.435    2
4  4 213.322    2
5  5 214.766    2
6  6 172.667    2
```

.. and so to `ID = 6`. I want to apply an autocorrelation function on each ID, i.e. compare `ID = 1` at time 1 with `ID = 1` at time 2 and so on.

What is the most straightforward way to apply e.g. `acf()` to my data frame?

When I try to use

```
autocorr = aggregate(x = DF$Area, by = list(DF$ID), FUN = acf)
```

I get a weird object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to apply an autocorrelation function on each ID

OK, good, so you don't want any cross-correlation, which make things much easier.

> I get a weird object

`acf` returns a bunch of things, i.e., it returns a list of things. I think you will be only interested in ACF values, so you need:

```
FUN = function (u) c(acf(u, plot = FALSE)$acf)
```

Also, using `aggregate` is not a good idea. You may want `split` and `sapply`:

```
## so your data frame is called `x`
oo <- sapply(split(x$Area, x$ID), FUN = function (u) c(acf(u, plot = FALSE)$acf) )
```

If you have balanced data, i.e., if you have equal number of observations for each `ID`, `oo` will be simplified into a matrix for sure. If you do not have balanced data, you may want to explicitly control the `lag.max` argument in `acf`. By default, `acf` will auto-decide on this value based on the number of observations.

Now suppose we want lag 0 to lag 7, we can set:

```
oo <- sapply(split(x$Area, x$ID),
             FUN = function (u) c(acf(u, plot = FALSE, lag.max = 7)$acf) )
```

Thus result `oo` is a matrix of 8 rows (row for lag, column for `ID`). I don't see any good of using a data frame to hold this result, but in case you want a data frame, simply do:

```
data.frame(oo)
```

With data either in a matrix or a data frame, it is easy for you to do further analysis.

### -----------

For a complete description of `acf`, please read [Produce a boxplot for multiple ACFs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41080942/4891738)

Comment: Thanks so much, that's informative! I see you wrote `function(x)` instead of `function(u)`. Also, the number of IDs varies with different time points. Thus, I cannot apply `data.frame(oo)`. In the end, I just need to plot the AC for every ID..

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! My problem is rather that IDs can disappear or emerge at a later time point. Thus, constraining `lag.max` doesn't help - I still get an object with varying row numbers. Now here comes my rather poor approach:

`num.el <- sapply(oo, length)`

`DF <- cbind(rep(1:length(oo), num.el),unlist(oo))`
`DF <- data.frame(DF)`
`plot(1:nrow(DF[DF$X1 == 1,]), DF$X2[DF$X1 == 1])`